# Inconsistent Flex Effects

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, flex4.5, effects

I've created a simple effect in Flex, code below, but it does not execute correctly...  When I rollOver the icon, MOST of the time the effect plays, and when I rollOut of the image the effect should play in reverse, but rarely does...

Is my code or logic incorrect?  FYI - I'm using Flash Builder 4.6.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
        <s:Move id="detail_fade" target="{detail_panel}" xFrom="218" xTo="400" />
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:Panel id="detail_panel" x="218" y="10" width="728" height="580" title="something">
    </s:Panel>

    <s:VGroup x="7" y="5" width="200" height="200">
        <s:Image source="images/Airfield Icon.jpg"
            rollOver="detail_fade.play()" rollOut="detail_fade.reverse()"/>
</s:VGroup>
```

Comment: FYI, detail_fade.reverse() will only work when isPlaying is true otherwise reverse() will not work.

Comment: Thank you, Mahesh!  The documentation says differently, but when I implemented a solution with your statement in mind it was successful, so you must be right....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mahesh pointed out in his comment, `reverse()` will only reverse an effect that is actually playing. Which is why you only see it happening sometimes: i.e. when you're quick enough to roll_out before the effect has ended.

You should instead use:

```
detail_fade.play(null, true);
```

The first argument of the `play` method, is an Array of the targets of your effect. Since you've already given it a target, you don't need to pass it again (that's why it says `null`).
The second argument is a Boolean telling the effect to play in the inverse direction if set to `true`. It is of course `false` by default.

---

Now, you may notice that when you roll_out quickly, the effect will jump to the end and start playing in the other direction from there.

This can be fixed like so:

```
if (detail_fade.isPlaying) detail_fade.reverse();
else detail_fade.play(null, true);
```